# Finding $T(e_{1})$ using identity matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\beta=\{e_{1},e_{2},e_{3},e_{4}\}$ the canonical basis of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ and $\gamma=\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4}\}$ an ordered basis of it.

The matrix of the linear operator $T$ on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ on basis $\gamma$ is
$$[T]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and it's also known that the identity transformation $I$ on $\mathbb{R}^{4}$ is such that
$$[I]_{\gamma}^{\beta}=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
and I have to evaluate $[T(e_{1})]_{\gamma}$.

I know that
$$[T]_{\beta}^{\beta}=[I]^{\gamma}_{\beta}\cdot[T]_{\gamma}^{\gamma}\cdot[I]^{\beta}_{\gamma}$$
$$\Rightarrow [T]_{\beta}=( [I]_{\gamma}^{\beta}) ^{-1}\cdot[T]_{\gamma}\cdot[I]^{\beta}_{\gamma}$$
so I can find $[T]_{\beta}$ and then, to conclude the exercise, I just have to evaluate
$$[T(e_{1})]_{\gamma}=[I]_{\gamma}^{\beta}\cdot[T(e_{1})]_{\beta}\cdot([I]^{\beta}_{\gamma})^{-1}$$
where
$$[T(e_{1})]_{\beta}=[T]_{\beta}\cdot\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Is it the right way to do it?